# Do Google Calendar Triggers execute in order?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

I run a google calendar trigger for every user (10k users) which notifies some external resources when something changes in the users calendar.

However I have some issues because it seems like the triggers don't always execute in order. When for example one user moves an event several times in a second it could be that the notification to an external resource of the last event movement hits first before the others do.

When I look into the Google Stackdriver logging I also could see that the same behavior when logging the trigger. But of course the issue could also be the logger itself.

How can I fix this when my business logic relies on the correct order of changes for a calendar? I know that there is also the [Push Notification for Calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) but there is no watch for a single calendar and this will also mean that I need to watch 10k of users which I don't think it's very practical.

So how can I solve this? Or am I wrong about the trigger execution order and the problem lies on the external resources execution order of requests?

Comment: I wonder if the trigger ids can help

Comment: do you mean the "insertID" ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en#eventupdated

Comment: ah I see, this id is always the same for one user and trigger. My issue is that the same trigger fires multiple times but not in order

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.  I thought that they might be sequential or something.

Comment: I've tried checking online about the trigger (including on the Google issue tracker) to see if there are any reported issue but there's none yet. Based on the documentation about [Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging), _"the logs stream in real time"_. If the logs from that specific Calendar trigger aren't tracked in order, then this could possibly be a logger issue. You may want to report an [Issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui) for this behavior & attach an image of the logged executions that aren't in real-time/ in order.

Comment: thank you, In my head the triggers are basically a cloudfunction which is kicked off, so if a trigger fires multiple times "in a very short period " then there is no way to keep the order